# how to solve error Legacy Context API in react?

Tags: reactjs, video-reactjs

This is my code:

`videoDetails` component ->

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { markLectureAsComplete } from "../../../services/operations/courseDetailsAPI";
import { updateCompletedLectures } from "../../../slices/viewCourseSlice";
import { Player } from "video-react";
import { BigPlayButton } from "video-react";
import "video-react/dist/video-react.css";

import IconBtn from "../../common/IconBtn";
import { AiFillPlayCircle } from "react-icons/ai";

const VideoDetails = () => {
  const { courseId, sectionId, subSectionId } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const location = useLocation();
  const playerRef = useRef();
  const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { courseSectionData, courseEntireData, completedLectures } =
    useSelector((state) => state.viewCourse);

  const [previewSource, setPreviewSource] = useState("");
  const [videoData, setVideoData] = useState([]);
  const [videoEnded, setVideoEnded] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setVideoSpecificDetails = async () => {
      if (!courseSectionData.length) return;
      if (!courseId && !sectionId && !subSectionId) {
        navigate("/dashboard/enrolled-courses");
      } else {
        //let's assume k all 3 fields are present
        const filteredData = courseSectionData.filter(
          (course) => course._id === sectionId
        );

        const filteredVideoData = filteredData?.[0].subSection.filter(
          (data) => data._id === subSectionId
        );

        setVideoData(filteredVideoData[0]);
        setPreviewSource(courseEntireData.thumbnail);
        setVideoEnded(false);
      }
    };
    setVideoSpecificDetails();
  }, [courseSectionData, courseEntireData, location.pathname]);
  console.log("COURSE SECTION DATA", courseSectionData, courseEntireData);

  const isFirstVideo = () => {
    const currentSectionIndex = courseSectionData.findIndex(
      (data) => data._id === sectionId
    );

    const currentSubSectionIndex = courseSectionData[
      currentSectionIndex
    ].subSectionId.findIndex((data) => data._id === subSectionId);
    if (currentSectionIndex === 0 && currentSubSectionIndex === 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  const isLastVideo = () => {
    const currentSectionIndex = courseSectionData.findIndex(
      (data) => data._id === sectionId
    );

    const noOfSubSections =
      courseSectionData[currentSectionIndex].subSection.length;

    const currentSubSectionIndex = courseSectionData[
      currentSectionIndex
    ].subSectionId.findIndex((data) => data._id === subSectionId);

    if (
      currentSectionIndex === courseSectionData.length - 1 &&
      currentSubSectionIndex === noOfSubSections - 1
    ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  const goToNextVideo = () => {
    const currentSectionIndex = courseSectionData.findIndex(
      (data) => data._id === sectionId
    );

    const noOfSubSections =
      courseSectionData[currentSectionIndex].subSection.length;

    const currentSubSectionIndex = courseSectionData[
      currentSectionIndex
    ].subSectionId.findIndex((data) => data._id === subSectionId);

    if (currentSubSectionIndex !== noOfSubSections - 1) {
      //same section ki next video me jao
      const nextSubSectionId =
        courseSectionData[currentSectionIndex].subSection[
          currentSectionIndex + 1
        ]._id;
      //next video pr jao
      navigate(
        `/view-course/${courseId}/section/${sectionId}/sub-section/${nextSubSectionId}`
      );
    } else {
      //different section ki first video
      const nextSectionId = courseSectionData[currentSectionIndex + 1]._id;
      const nextSubSectionId =
        courseSectionData[currentSectionIndex + 1].subSection[0]._id;
      ///iss voide par jao
      navigate(
        `/view-course/${courseId}/section/${nextSectionId}/sub-section/${nextSubSectionId}`
      );
    }
  };

  const goToPrevVideo = () => {
    const currentSectionIndex = courseSectionData.findIndex(
      (data) => data._id === sectionId
    );

    const noOfSubSections =
      courseSectionData[currentSectionIndex].subSection.length;

    const currentSubSectionIndex = courseSectionData[
      currentSectionIndex
    ].subSectionId.findIndex((data) => data._id === subSectionId);

    if (currentSubSectionIndex !== 0) {
      //same section , prev video
      const prevSubSectionId =
        courseSectionData[currentSectionIndex].subSection[
          currentSubSectionIndex - 1
        ];
      //iss video par chalge jao
      navigate(
        `/view-course/${courseId}/section/${sectionId}/sub-section/${prevSubSectionId}`
      );
    } else {
      //different section , last video
      const prevSectionId = courseSectionData[currentSectionIndex - 1]._id;
      const prevSubSectionLength =
        courseSectionData[currentSectionIndex - 1].subSection.length;
      const prevSubSectionId =
        courseSectionData[currentSectionIndex - 1].subSection[
          prevSubSectionLength - 1
        ]._id;
      //iss video par chalge jao
      navigate(
        `/view-course/${courseId}/section/${prevSectionId}/sub-section/${prevSubSectionId}`
      );
    }
  };

  const handleLectureCompletion = async () => {
    ///dummy code, baad me we will replace it witht the actual call
    setLoading(true);
    //PENDING - > Course Progress PENDING
    const res = await markLectureAsComplete(
      { courseId: courseId, subSectionId: subSectionId },
      token
    );
    //state update
    if (res) {
      dispatch(updateCompletedLectures(subSectionId));
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-5 text-white">
      {!videoData ? (
        <img
          src={previewSource}
          alt="Preview"
          className="h-full w-full rounded-md object-cover"
        />
      ) : (
        <Player
          ref={playerRef}
          aspectRatio="16:9"
          playsInline
          onEnded={() => setVideoEnded(true)}
          src={videoData?.videoUrl}
        >
          <AiFillPlayCircle
            fontSize={25}
            position="center"
            className="text-white"
          />
          {/* Render When Video Ends */}
          {videoEnded && (
            <div
              style={{
                backgroundImage:
                  "linear-gradient(to top, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
              }}
              className="full absolute inset-0 z-[100] grid h-full place-content-center font-inter"
            >
              {!completedLectures.includes(subSectionId) && (
                <IconBtn
                  disabled={loading}
                  onclick={() => handleLectureCompletion()}
                  text={!loading ? "Mark As Completed" : "Loading..."}
                  customClasses="text-xl max-w-max px-4 mx-auto"
                />
              )}
              <IconBtn
                disabled={loading}
                onclick={() => {
                  if (playerRef?.current) {
                    // set the current time of the video to 0
                    playerRef?.current?.seek(0);
                    setVideoEnded(false);
                  }
                }}
                text="Rewatch"
                customClasses="text-xl max-w-max px-4 mx-auto mt-2"
              />
              <div className="mt-10 flex min-w-[250px] justify-center gap-x-4 text-xl">
                {!isFirstVideo() && (
                  <button
                    disabled={loading}
                    onClick={goToPrevVideo}
                    className="blackButton"
                  >
                    Prev
                  </button>
                )}
                {!isLastVideo() && (
                  <button
                    disabled={loading}
                    onClick={goToNextVideo}
                    className="blackButton"
                  >
                    Next
                  </button>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </Player>
      )}
      <h1 className="mt-4 text-3xl font-semibold">{videoData?.title}</h1>
      <p className="pt-2 pb-6">{videoData?.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoDetails;
```

[image]

I am creating custom video player with `React` library - **video-react**.
In this video component `Player`

I want play video with different section and subSection just like whenever clicked on next goes to next video as well as prevoius button.

Video player is not working and it shows error I have attached screenshot.

Error:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code or errors. Screenshots are not searchable and do not work with screenreaders. Please paste code/errors as text in code blocks: ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code and the error message provided, it seems like the issue is with the Player component from the video-react library. The error is likely due to the incorrect usage of the AiFillPlayCircle component within the Player component.

To fix this issue, you should remove the AiFillPlayCircle component from the Player component, as it seems to be causing a conflict or rendering issue. Instead, you can use the BigPlayButton component provided by the video-react library to show a play button on the video player.

Here's the modified code:

```
// Remove this import
// import { AiFillPlayCircle } from "react-icons/ai";

// ...

// Inside the Player component, remove the AiFillPlayCircle and use 
BigPlayButton
<Player
  ref={playerRef}
  aspectRatio="16:9"
  playsInline
  onEnded={() => setVideoEnded(true)}
  src={videoData?.videoUrl}
>
{/* Use BigPlayButton instead of AiFillPlayCircle */}
<BigPlayButton position="center" className="text-white" />
{/* Render When Video Ends */}
{videoEnded && (
 // ... (rest of the code remains unchanged)
)}
</Player>
```

By using BigPlayButton instead of AiFillPlayCircle, you should be able to resolve the issue.

Comment: i change AiFillPlayCircle with BigPlayButton but   There is some other error given Below   with  tag name-> ERROR image please check it